# "tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory" causes series of "Cleanup called..." messages in notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, kaggle

I am trying to implement a simple classification model, but there seems to be a problem with the "Dataset" object.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
```

The code to generate training dataset is:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
   TRAIN_DIR,
   validation_split = 0.25,
   seed = 3,
   image_size = (224, 224), 
   batch_size = batch_size,
   subset = 'training',
   shuffle = True,
   labels = 'inferred',
   label_mode = 'categorical'
)
```

and for validation it is:

```
validation_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR,
    validation_split = 0.25,
    seed = 3,
    image_size = (224, 224), 
    batch_size = batch_size,
    subset = 'validation',
    shuffle = True,
    labels = 'inferred',
    label_mode = 'categorical'
)
```

i dont think there is anything special about the code but when i execute the following code:

```
class_names = train_ds.class_names

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
      for i in range(9):
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(labels[i])])
        plt.axis("off")
```

it shows "Cleanup called..." in several lines.

same thing happens when i try to fit the model using `model.fit` function.

I am using a simple `Kaggle` notebook and `tensorflow` version is `2.6.4`.

i tried several solutions found in the site, such as downgrading to a lower version of `tensorflow`, but in that case `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` does not seem to work at all.

i tried to hide error messages by:

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

and this didn't work either.

i tried rest of the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911252/disable-tensorflow-debugging-information), but they didn't.

I checked other codes for the same dataset, they were using the deprecated [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator).

So my question is, is there a work around or a simple solution to disable these "Cleanup Called..." messages and still use `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`?

PS: Most of the code is copied from [Image Classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification), when implementing this dataset there seems to be no problem, but when implementing other datasets, that are added to the `input` or `output` of a kernel, this problem occures.

Comment: Hi @MeBottleOScrumpy, found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73256702/14290697), it might help in resolving the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @Tfer3 thanks mate, but the link you provided suggests downgrading `tensorflow`, which i stated in the question creates problems with `image_dataset_from_directory`.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73219868/14290697), you can try using `from IPython.display import clear_output` followed by 
`clear_output()` whithout downgrading the version of Tensorflow

Comment: @Tfer3 even thought it hides progress bars and stuff it is nice work around. thanks.

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution to just suppress the annoying `Cleanup called` message? I am currently facing the same problem and tbh, I do not want to get rid of all messages, but just the Clean up called. Or to know how to avoid it in the first place...

Comment: @Cedric No, but you can try `ImageDataGenerator` or writing your own `keras.utils.Sequence` which is not that difficult, involves few more steps and gives you a tat more control during fetching of each batch and related augmentations, or things you can do to your dataset such as shuffling after each epoch, but it involves few lines of extra code, [here](https://keras.io/api/utils/python_utils/#sequence-class) is an example of it.