# "Cleanup called..." while loading MNIST Datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm using TensorFlow to load the MNIST dataset, and it keeps printing "Cleanup called..." on the output cell continuously.

[image]

And this also happens when I start the training.

I am using tf version `2.6.4`

Code:

```
train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    as_supervised=True
)
```

```
def normalize_img(image, label):
    return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255., label
```

```
train_ds = train_ds.map(normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(len(train_ds))
train_ds = train_ds.batch(128)
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

```
next(iter(train_ds))
```

Output:

```
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
Cleanup called...
...
```

I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72129656/getting-the-message-cleanup-called-repeatedly-while-training-a-model-on-kag) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71969321/tensorflow-decode-png-keeps-printing-cleanup-called) question. But the only solution there is to downgrade TensorFlow, which I do not want to do.

How can I properly load the data so that this message never appears?

Comment: Are you in kaggle env? If so, there're pretty much nothing you can do except downgrade. [Check.](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/google-universal-image-embedding/discussion/340586)

Comment: I fixed the problem by loading the MNIST array and then calling `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` which hopefully worked. However, if I come across a larger dataset the next time, I won't be able to load it all in array, therefore I'll have to downgrade it, thanks for the suggestion.